# Concurrent calls to API to return different object

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following scenario

Query results:

```
student1  subject1  marks1
student2  subject1  marks3
...
...
```

The API code looks like this

```
StudentObj getStudentInfo() {
    List<StudentObj> stObj = StudentDAO.getRows(); //

    for (StudentObj s : stObj) {
       //What should I write here??
    }
}
```

I want to be able to return student1 rows, student2 rows separately in concurrent calls to my API.

I am using Hibernate (to which I am relatively new) on top of oracle database.

I was thinking in lines of locking student1 row and returning that row, but I am not very conversant with locking in hibernate.

On Client Side

```
time t1: getStudentInfo() (work on student1) |  getStudentInfo() //Call concurrently (work on student2)

time t1+10sec: getStudentInfo (work on student3)
time t1+20sec: getStudentInfo (work on student4)
```

First call should be able to work on student1 and second concurrent call should be able to work on student2.

Edit: Made changes based on comments. ( I cannot edit the query and clients getStudentInfo cannot pass the id if that helps).

Comment: Are you asking how to use filters with hibernate?

Comment: Nope but how should I go about using locks (if it is correct) to return distinct student objects to clients of the API.

Comment: apparently i might have mis-understood your question. Can you provide more details

Comment: The query returns the results as shown above with students, subjects and the respective marks. Lets call the API getStudentInfo(), if calls are made to getStudentInfo then it should operate on student1 rows, whereas concurrently if calls are made to getStudentInfo it should be able to work on student2. Let me know if this helps

Comment: so ONLY if a concurrent request is made then it should return "student2" data otherwise (if there is no concurrent request then it should return "student1" data?

Comment: Changed the question to reflect , sorry about the confusion.

Comment: so every subsequent call should return the next student's info?

Comment: then why did you specify "concurrent call". this should be "subsequent" call...

Comment: Actually the calls can be concurrent as well as subsequent  if you look at the question , i have edited with the timeline of events it should help.

Comment: also if I provided the answer then accept it as the actual answer ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited: Synchronize the method, and keep an iterator of students and return the next one for each call.

```
Iterator<StudentObj> students;

synchronized StudentObj getStudentInfo() {
    if (null == students || !students.hasNext()) {
        students = StudentDAO.getRows().iterator();
    }
    return students.next();
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the method signature can't be changed as it means change in the client code

Answer (score 2):

See if the below code helps. All you need to do here is to make sure the sequenceNumber is assigned a proper starting value. This is the best I can provide based on the info you provided.

I am still confused on why you mentioned hibernate when you can't modify the queries. How is your query written by the way? I see there is a potential to use the Hibernate Filters but you still somehow needs to maintain the sequenceNumber somewhere. It is hard to provide proper solution without knowing more details.

```
class SomeClass 
{
    private final static AtomicLong sequenceNumber = new AtomicLong(0);
    public static long next() 
    { 
        return sequenceNumber.getAndIncrement(); 
    }

    StudentObj getStudentInfo() 
    {
        List<StudentObj> stObj = StudentDAO.getRows(); //

        for (StudentObj s : stObj) 
        {
            long filter = next();
           //use filter to send the appropriate student info
        }
    }
}
```